# Comparing String DateTime in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have `DateTime` value stored in a `VARCHAR` type column in a database and now I want to compare dates in select query but it's giving me an error. The value stored in the column looks like this `17/3/14 03:07:03`

Here is what I have tried

```
select * 
from [User]
WHERE myDate > convert(datetime, '31-5-2012')
```

Comment: Best medium to long term fix is to fix the database to be using appropriate data types. Conversion from string to datetime ought to be one of the first things done with user input, well up in the UI and away from the database. Similarly, converting datetime to string ought to be one of the last things done with data before its presented to the users.

Comment: "I have DateTime value stored in a VARCHAR type field in database" Well, that's your first problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
SET DateFormat DMY

SELECT * FROM [User]
WHERE myDate > CAST('31-5-2012' AS DATETIME)
```